# How to get item details from Listview on another activity

Tags: android

I have tried many methods but still not working.
almost used all methods from stackoverflow's answers. but not working.

MainActivity.java

```
mProductList = new ArrayList<>();
        //add sample data to list

        mProductList.add(new Product(1, "iPhone4", 200, "Apple1"));
        mProductList.add(new Product(2, "iPhone5", 2100, "Apple2"));
        mProductList.add(new Product(3, "iPhone6", 2020, "Apple3"));
        mProductList.add(new Product(4, "iPhone7", 2400, "Apple4"));
        mProductList.add(new Product(5, "iPhone8", 2050, "Apple5"));
        mProductList.add(new Product(6, "iPhone9", 7200, "Apple6"));

        //init adapter
        adapter = new ProductListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mProductList);
        lvProduct.setAdapter(adapter);


        lvProduct.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked product id =" + view.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Product item = (Product)lvProduct.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                Log.d("abc",item.getName());

                Intent launchActivity1= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Show.class);
                launchActivity1.putExtra("item", item.getName());
                startActivity(launchActivity1);
            }
        });
```

and Show.java

```
public class Show extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.show);
    }
    Intent launchActivity1 = getIntent();
    String item = launchActivity1.getStringExtra("item"); // this is line 17
}
```

when i click on one item it shows item name in Log with "getName()" function.
but at the same time app crashes and show error in Show.java on line 17

please help me to solve this code.

this error is showing in Log

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.Serializable android.content.Intent.getSerializableExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at com.example.sohaib.mydesign.Show.<init>(Show.java:17)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another-on-android

Comment: If you would like to fix your end bracket for the onCreate method, that would be great if you could [edit] your question to do that and include the full logcat

Comment: The intent is null because it's outside a method...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is outside onCreate method!

```
Intent launchActivity1 = getIntent();
String item = launchActivity1.getStringExtra("item");
```

Put this inside onCreate. Also onCreate doesn't have override annotation.

Comment: and please tell me how to create onCreate override annotation

Comment: Put `@Override` on line above `onCreate`
The code which you shared has Intent inside activity block but outside onCreate. Check again!

Comment: The annotation doesn't do anything special other than tell the compiler that the method should be overriden. Simply having the same method signature is what actually overrides the method

Answer (score 0):

> Copy paste this instead in your Show.java

```
public class Show extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.show);
    Intent launchActivity1 = getIntent();
    String item = launchActivity1.getStringExtra("item"); // this is line 17
}
```

}

Comment: `item.getName()` does this method return a string?

Comment: when i move my cursor on item in Product item = (Product)parent.getAdapter().getItem(position); it says varriable 'item' is never used.
and in show.java it show varriable 'item' is never used at this line... String item = launchActivity1.getStringExtra("item");

Answer (score 0):

add it in oncreate block...

```
public class Show extends Activity {
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           ................
           ................


     Intent launchActivity1 = getIntent();
    String item = launchActivity1.getStringExtra("item"); // this is line 17
    }
}
```

Or it happens when you pass object instead of string. So use

```
launchActivity1.putExtra("item", ""+item.getName());
```

thanks..

and in onclick should be..

```
Product item = (Product)parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
```

Comment: when i move my cursor on item in

Product item = (Product)parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);

it says varriable 'item' is never used.

Comment: and same in both pages Mainactivity and Show.java

in show.java it show varriable 'item' is never used at this line...

 String item = launchActivity1.getStringExtra("item");

Comment: did you try this?   "String item= getIntent().getExtras().getString("item");"

Comment: not working. why this happening to me. i am getting value in log but can't pass to another activity. :(

Comment: when i click i get value in Log 
06-17 11:21:21.758 9567-9567/com.example.sohaib.mydesign D/abc: iPhone4

Answer (score 0):

I have Solved the issue on my own. thank you all of you for your quick response... solution is...

MainActivity.java

```
lvProduct.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked product id =" + view.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Product item = (Product)lvProduct.getAdapter().getItem(position);

                Intent launchActivity1= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Show.class);
                launchActivity1.putExtra("item", item.getName());
                startActivity(launchActivity1);


            }
        });
```

Show.java

```
public class Show extends Activity {

    String passedVar = null;
    private TextView passedView= null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.show);
       passedVar = getIntent().getStringExtra("item");
        passedView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pass);
        passedView.setText("You= " + passedVar);
    }
}
```